# How to deploy Workflow engine on jBOSS AS 7

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jbpm, bpmn

I have running jBOSS AS 7 and I want to deploy my Workflow engine on this server. How can I do it? I have files .bpmn and .java. In .bpmn file I have scenario and in .java file I have class with functions which I'm using in my .bpmn file.
Please help me.

Greetings
rizon

Comment: did you try to create a war with files and deploy that?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer.
How Can I do war from this files in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options:
(1) write your own web application that embeds the jBPM jars and calls the process at some point in time, this requires you to write a web app, embed all the jbpm jars and create a war from this to deploy
(2) take advantage of the jBPM console to deploy and execute your process on the jBPM execution server, you should install the jbpm-console and use the authoring environment to build and deploy your process and the management UI to start and manage your process instances.  You can use git to sync your process in Eclipse with the jbpm-console.  Consider using the jbpm-installer to install and start the jbpm-console on as7

Note that for (1) you need to have sufficient web development capabilities before you can get started with this.  In this case, it seems going for (2) seems to be recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much! First I will try option 1, i will write here my progress.

Regards

Comment: You're right, I use second option :) But now I want add my engine (.java file and .bpmn file) to jbpm-console and I don't know how, I have jbpm-console.war in deployment in jBoss AS 7 and what now?